# Why did I get a seg fault (segmentation fault) in this code

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char fileName[50] = {};
    char fileLine[200] = {};
    char *token = NULL;
    char *delimiters = " \n\t";
    FILE *FH = NULL;

    //step 1e to 1g
    strcpy(fileName, argv[1]);
    FH = fopen(fileName, "r+");
    if (FH == NULL)
    {
        printf("File did not open\nExiting...");
        exit(0);
    }
```

For some reason this code keeps seg faulting. I used valgrind to ID the issue at the strcpy line and it says:

```
Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

I tried to run it in OnlineGDB and it went all the way to the first print statement:

```
File did not open\nExiting...
```

I tried increasing the size of fileName, but even at 1000 it didn't work. I tried decreasing it to 20, but it didn't work either.

Comment: This code presumes `argv[1]` is not NULL... Risky...

Comment: `char fileName[50] = {};` isn't valid C (yet).

Comment: When this condition is meet, `!argv[1] || strlen(argv[1])>=50`  you have UB.

Comment: Plkease, read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)  and edit your question to show a compilable and runnable example.  We cannot work guessing what you could have tried to do.  Also, please provide examples of input, actual output and desired output, in order to be able to make a full diagnostic of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the program was invoked with at least one argument. If no arguments are provided, `argv[1]` is `NULL`, hence the segfault.

BTW You also should call `exit(1)` (not `exit(0)`) in case of failure.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    char filename[50] = {};
    char fileLine[200] = {};
    char *token = NULL;
    char *delimiters = " \n\t";
    FILE *FH = NULL;

    // ADD THIS
    if (argc < 2)
    {
       printf("You need to provide a file name\n");
       exit(1);
    }
    //

    //step 1e to 1g
    strcpy(filename, argv[1]);
    FH = fopen(filename, "r+");
    if (FH == NULL)
    {
        printf("File did not open\nExiting...");
        exit(1);  // BTW use exit(1) for failure
    }
```

**Disclaimer:**
This code is still poor because it blindly copies `argv[1]` into `filename`, and as `filename` can contain no more than 49 characters this can go very wrong.

Comment: You forgot to check if `argv[1]`, is longer than 49 characters (allowing 1 extra for the null character).  File paths can easily be longer than that. But in this case, it would be better to just make `filename` a pointer and set it to `argv[1]`, rather than copying it.  But if it really needs to be copied, it would be better to use `strdup` rather than a fixed-sized array.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a good answer, but the seg fault ended up being in a completely different part of the code. I didn't see it until I debugged the entire program.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).